# Random keyboard keys stopped working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, hardware-failure

After rebooting my laptop (a recently purchased mid/high-end Asus running Windows 10), my 2, 4, 7, 9, t, and l keys stopped working. All my other keys are fine. I have rebooted the computer, updated the keyboard driver and OS, and uninstalled the driver.

I would greatly appreciate tips on how to debug and hopefully remedy the issue.

Comment: Do they work in the BIOS, or in another OS (Linux live, for example)?  If not, then it's a hardware problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Certain keys on my keyboard stopped working](https://superuser.com/questions/382511/certain-keys-on-my-keyboard-stopped-working)

Answer (score 0):

@Techie007 is correct. Break it down to the core to troubleshoot, aka BIOS. If it works there, then you can start troubleshooting OS/driver issues. If not, then start by resetting the cable or replacing the keyboard. Most keyboards on laptops are low to replace and fairly easy to install.